# How to grab one value being returned from a function without rerunning the function? Python

Tags: python

Within my code, I am running two function which are both returning 3 things, (2 list, 1 float). I would like to add the two functions float values together to recieve the desired result.

Essentialy the code is

```
def fun1(...):
    ...
    return list11, list12, float1

def fun2(...):
    ...
    return list21, list22, float2

floatSum = float1+float2
```

I am able to make a graph from the returned list. However, I am not able to complete the floatSum calculation

Comment: Unpack the returned tuple into 3 separate variables from each function call and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the float values you can do it like this:

```py
_, _, float1 = fun1(...)
_, _, float2 = fun2(...)

float_sum = float1 + float2
```

This is an example of tuple unpacking:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpacking-tuple/

Answer (score 0):

Each function returns a tuple, you can access individual item in tuple by indexing like lists.

```
def fun1(...):
    ...
    return list11, list12, float1

def fun2(...):
    ...
    return list21, list22, float2

floatSum = fun1()[2]+fun2()[2]
```